# Can you pass multi-dimensional arrays into a C function as pointers and then cast them back into arrays inside the function?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

**Problem:** suppose you are trying to write a function in C that will fill a 2D array with values from a file.  The file contains the values arranged in rows (records), where each row contains a number of fields.  The function should take in a pointer to the 2D array and the address of the file and fill in the array.  Importantly, the function should work independently of how many fields there are per record.  For example, in one program you might call the function to read values from a file where there are four fields per record:

```
int array_of_values[MAX_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS][4];
fill_in_array(array_of_values, "spacetime.csv");
```

In another program, you might want to fill in values when there are eleven fields per record:

```
int array_of_values[MAX_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS][11];
fill_in_array(array_of_values, "M-theory.csv");
```

Unfortunately, if you try to do this you fall foul of the way C handles multidimensional arrays.  Multidimensional arrays are not implemented in C as arrays of pointers to arrays, but instead as one long one-dimensional array.  This means that the function needs to know the width of the array in order to read data from it.

So the following function definition will give you an error:

```
void fill_in_array(int array_of_values[MAX_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS][], char *path)
```

[Note that the following would be fine:

```
void fill_in_array(int array_of_values[][MAX_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS], char *path)
```

since the compiler does not need to know the index for the first dimension, but suppose that this is not allowed (e.g., if the function needs to mess around with individual records like `array_of_values[1]`).]

This is the point that I have reached in my program.  There are two solutions that present themselves:

1. Force the function to work with a fixed number of fields.  I'd obviously rather not do this, but I could, for example, declare a constant `MAX_NUMBER_OF_FIELDS` and leave unused fields empty.
2. Make the `fill_in_array` function take in a pointer rather than an array and dynamically allocate an Iliffe vector containing the fields.  This is an attractive idea (since it would stop us having to declare a maximum number of records/fields, but it would also mean we would have to create (and remember to use!) a function to free the array of fields.

I've got one other idea.  That is to modify the declaration of the function to the following:

```
void fill_in_array(int **array_of_values, int number_of_fields, char *path)
```

(Here, `number_of_fields` refers to the number of fields per record, so we might call it as `fill_in_array(array_of_values, 4, "spacetime.csv");`.

Notice that the parameter `array_of_values` is no longer an explicit array, but is a pointer.  Normally, if you assign a double-pointer to point to a 2D array, the result is meaningless.  My idea is that it might be possible to use the `number_of_fields` parameter so that the function knows how to deal with expressions like `array_of_values[i][j]`.

In principle this should be fairly easy: indeed, if `a` is a 2D array, then `a[i][j]` is defined to be

```
*(a + (i * n) + j)
```

where `n` is the length of the array, so we could replace every occurrence of `array_of_values[i][j]` with `*(array_of_values + (i * number_of_fields) + j)`, and every occurrence of `array_of_values[i]` with `array_of_values + (i * number_of_fields)`.  This code would be very hard to read, however.  Is there some way of telling the compiler that the width of the array is `number_of_fields` so that I can use index notation to access elements of the array?

Comment: `Multidimensional arrays are not implemented in C as arrays of arrays, but instead as one long one-dimensional array` (a) No they're not, and (b) I fail to understand the distinction.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  What I meant was: `Arrays of arrays` = Iliffe vector (i.e., one-dimensional array whose elements are the addresses of one-dimensional arrays; elements are accessed using the formula `a[i][j] = *(*(a + i) + j)`) - this is NOT how they're implemented in C; `One long one-dimensional array` = one-dimensional array of m*n elements, where m,n are the dimensions of the array; elements are accessed as `a[i][j] = *(a + (i * n) + j)` - this is how they're implemented in C, which means the compiler needs to know the value of `n`.

Comment: So what you meant to say was "arrays of pointers to arrays", which is a _very_ different (and inferior) thing.

Comment: Yes OK.  I'll correct it.  Also, it is not an entirely inferior thing.  It is inferior from the point of view of performance and caching, but it's a more natural extension of 1d arrays and doesn't require knowledge of the dimensions of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions.

Use a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  // whatever appears in a record
} record_t

void fill_in_array(record_t records[MAX_NUMBER_OF_RECORDS], const char* path);
```

Note that this only makes sense if the size of a record is known at compile time, which given your example, it may not be.

Use a stride:

```
void fill_in_array(int *array_of_values, int stride, const char *path)
{
  #define IDX(x, y) (x + (y * stride))

  // get the val at i,j
  int val = array_of_values[IDX(i,j)];

  #undef IDX
}
```

You've suggested this approach in your function with `number_of_fields` which is a stride, however stride is a term which other developers looking at your code are more likely to recognize.

One minor unrelated point, if you don't change the contents of `path`, you should make it `const` :)

Comment: OK thanks - as you can see from my question, I was contemplating adding a stride (though I didn't know that that was what it was called).  That's what I'm going to do, since I'd rather not assume anything about how the records are set up.

Comment: Is it good coding practice to use `#define`s inside functions, though?  I've been brought up only to use them in header files.

Comment: You might name your macro something slightly different to ensure you don't get a name collision (IDX is a bit short, but this is an SO answer not production code :P ). You should include a matching undef, I am updating my code now :)

Comment: OK thanks - I suppose that if `stride` is a commonly used term for this kind of thing then I could define IDX in a header file anyway, since it always expands to `(x + (y * stride))`.  I'd need to make sure that I always called that parameter `stride`, which isn't ideal, but it would be nice to standardize the treatment of multidimensional arrays across all my programs.

Comment: If your macro assumes the presence of a particular local variable (in this case `stride`) it doesn't make sense to put it in a header. However if it looked like `#define IDX(x, y, stride) (x + (y * stride))` you could argue for putting it in a header.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no such way.

Once you need to have generic address computation, you need to implement it yourself.

Congratualations for arriving at the solution of adding an explicit parameter that describes the number of fields per record, that's certainly how it should be done.

You can use a macro inside the function to make the address calculation more easily managable, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking exists in C++, but not in C, I believe. In C++ you can define template functions for working with arrays of size, known at a compile time, and compiler takes care of the rest. In C, there are two approaches:

- Define the size explicitly
  This is the case of functions like `memcpy`, where you specify number of elements

  ```
  void process_array(int *data[], size_t max_x, size_t max_y)
  ....
  ```
- Define the size using invalid number
  This is the case of functions like `strlen` where data is terminated by certain value (`'\0'` here)
  So if you want to have a function with matrix, but variable number of elements, you must define a way how to indicate that in the data.

  ```
  #define ARRAY_TERM -1

  void process_array(int *data[])
  {
      size_t i, j;
      for (i = 0; data[i]; i++)
      {
          for (j = 0; data[i][j] != ARRAY_TERM; j++)
          {
             ...
          }
      }
  }
  ...
  ```

Hope you've got the idea. Not very convenient to use.

There is another approach: define your own type. Yes, it is a viable option in many cases:

```
typedef struct array *array_t;
struct array
{
    size_t max_x, max_y;
    int *data;
};
```

Basic set of functions to work with it:

```
int array_init(array_t *a; size_t max_x, size_t max_y)
{
    array_t res;
    res = malloc(sizeof(*res));
    res->max_x = max_x;
    res->max_y = max_y;
    res->data = calloc(max_x * max_y, sizeof(int));
    *a = res;
    return 0;
}

void array_destroy(array_t *a)
{
    free((*a)->data);
    free(*a);
}
```

And then you can define your additional functions for operation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are limited to C89 (i.e. the MSVC compiler), you can pass multi-dimensional arrays around like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fill_in_array(size_t m, size_t n, int array_of_values[m][n])
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      array_of_values[i][j] = ((i == j) ? 1 : 0);
    }
  }
}

void print_array(size_t m, size_t n, int array_of_values[m][n])
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      printf(" %d", array_of_values[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main()
{
  {
    int array_of_values[2][4];
    fill_in_array(2, 4, array_of_values);
    print_array(2, 4, array_of_values);
  }
  {
    size_t h = 6, w = 5;
    int array_of_values[h][w];
    fill_in_array(h, w, array_of_values);
    print_array(h, w, array_of_values);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty cool that you can do that in C99, but I'd rather keep my code portable.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: Well it is portable... to everywhere except MSVC.

Comment: Unfortunately, MSVC is exactly the compiler I'm using.